# clicking a link that loads the chrome debugger with errors

Tags: manual-testing

I have an issue with a delete item link in my webpage. It is supposed to do nothing (after
some conditions become true) but I noticed that the chrome debugger is generating internal 
server errors each time i click the link.

Should I inform the developer with that issue? Is it even an issue at all?!

The error is:

```
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If your server responds with a 500 error, you should notify your developer.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error

Comment: No problem.  My motto: "When in doubt, write a bug report." In the best case, you've notified the right people about a critical issue. In the worst case, someone reads it and dismisses it as unimportant. But if you keep it to yourself, everyone loses.

Comment: Not quite the same thing, but this might help: http://www.allthingsquality.com/2010/04/non-reproducible-bugs.html You only fail when you don't write the bug report.

Comment: i took ur advice and reported the bug,but i wanna know under what types of bugs this bug categorized?!

Comment: (shrug) How about Server Error?

Comment: :D ok,thaaaanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is the generic error given when 'something' goes wrong in a server. You have to report this error to your development team. They should have the appropriate logging to deal with the problem.